# Helps with TGrid

Tags: c++, c++builder, tgrid

I'm a newbie in C++ Builder and really need some help.  In my work, we have to use C++ Builder and I can't find very much documentation about it.

What I want to do is to insert a new row with some data in each column each time the user press the <kbd>Insert</kbd> key. There are 20 rows in total in my TGrid: 1 `TCheckColumn` and 19 `TStringColumn`.

I don't know how to do it exactly.  First, here is the code I already wrote when someone enter the insert key:

```
void __fastcall TForm2::Grid1KeyDown(TObject *Sender, WORD &Key, System::WideChar &KeyChar,
        TShiftState Shift)
{
    switch(Key)
    {
        case VK_INSERT:
            if(Grid1->RowCount>MAXTask){}else
            {
                Label1->Text  = "number Task: "+IntToStr(++nmbertask);
                Grid1->RowCount++;
            }
            break;
    }
}
```

Here is the `Grid1GetValue()` and `Grid1SetValue()` code:

```
void __fastcall TForm2::Grid1GetValue(TObject *Sender, const int Col, const int Row,
    TValue &Value)
{
    switch(Col)
    {
        case 0:
            Value = A[Col][Row]; break;
        case 1:
            Value = A[Col][Row]; break;
        case 2:
            Value = A[Col][Row]; break;
        case 3:
            Value = A[Col][Row]; break;
        case 4:
            Value = A[Col][Row]; break;
        case 5:
            Value = A[Col][Row]; break;
        case 6:
            Value = A[Col][Row]; break;
        case 7:
            Value = A[Col][Row]; break;
        case 8:
            Value = A[Col][Row]; break;
        case 9:
            Value = A[Col][Row];break;
        case 10:
            Value = A[Col][Row];break;
        case 11:
            Value = A[Col][Row];break;
        case 12:
            Value = A[Col][Row];break;
        case 13:
            Value = A[Col][Row];break;
        case 14:
            Value = A[Col][Row];break;
        case 15:
            Value = A[Col][Row];break;
        case 16:
            Value = A[Col][Row];break;
        case 17:
            Value = A[Col][Row];break;
        case 18:
            Value = A[Col][Row]; break;
        case 19:
            Value = A[Col][Row];break;
    }
}

void __fastcall TForm2::Grid1SetValue(TObject *Sender, const int Col, const int Row,
    const TValue &Value)
{
    switch(Col)
    {
        case 0:
            A[Col][Row] = Value; break;
        case 1:
            A[Col][Row] = Value; break;
        case 2:
            A[Col][Row] = Value; break;
        case 3:
            A[Col][Row] = Value; break;
        case 4:
            A[Col][Row] = Value; break;
        case 5:
            A[Col][Row] = Value; break;
        case 6:
            A[Col][Row] = Value; break;
        case 7:
            A[Col][Row] = Value; break;
        case 8:
            A[Col][Row] = Value; break;
        case 9:
            A[Col][Row] = Value; break;
        case 10:
            A[Col][Row] = Value; break;
        case 11:
            A[Col][Row] = Value; break;
        case 12:
            A[Col][Row] = Value; break;
        case 13:
            A[Col][Row] = Value; break;
        case 14:
            A[Col][Row] = Value; break;
        case 15:
            A[Col][Row] = Value; break;
        case 16:
            A[Col][Row] = Value; break;
        case 17:
            A[Col][Row] = Value; break;
        case 18:
            A[Col][Row] = Value; break;
        case 19:
            A[Col][Row] = Value; break;
    }
}
```

This is what I've done so far. I've never developed in C++ Builder, so can you help me please? I'm not really looking for a written solution, I'm really looking for an indication of where to look for a solution.

If I'm not clear, please indicate it so I can give more information. If you also have a good site with good documentation about C++ Builder, please indicate it to me. English is not my native language but I will do my best.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find the [`TGrid` documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/FMX.Grid.TGrid) on [Embarcadero's DocWiki](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com). Look at the 'Methods' page to figure out how to insert and remove elements in your `TGrid`. There are two methods that can help you: `InsertComponent()` and `InsertObject().

Also, in your `Grid1GetValue()` and `Grid1SetValue()` methods, you are using a `switch` statement. In all those cases you are doing the same job :

```
Value = A[Col][Row];break;
```

So, instead of using a `switch`, you can simply call one time `Value = A[Col][Row];` and it will do the same result.

I hope my answer can help you. At least I answered what I understood from your question.